# Check to see if a MongoDB collection is capped with the .NET 2.0 driver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

With the now legacy .NET MongoDB driver I used to use the following to create a capped collection if it didn't already exist (not bulletproof, but it stopped us accidentally using uncapped collections on several occasions):

```
private MongoCollection GetCappedCollection(string collectionName, long maxSize)
{
    if (!this.database.CollectionExists(collectionName))
        CreateCollection(collectionName, maxSize);

    MongoCollection<BsonDocument> cappedCollection = this.database.GetCollection(collectionName);
    if (!cappedCollection.IsCapped())
        throw new MongoException(
            string.Format("A capped collection is required but the \"{0}\" collection is not capped.", collectionName));

    return cappedCollection;
}

private void CreateCappedCollection(string collectionName, long maxSize)
{
    this.database.CreateCollection(collectionName,
                                   CollectionOptions
                                      .SetCapped(true)
                                      .SetMaxSize(maxSize));
}
```

How can I do the same with the new 2.0 version of the .NET MongoDB driver? Ideally I'd like to keep the same behavior as above but it would be good enough to throw the exception. While it's possible to create a capped collection using `CreateCollectionAsync` it doesn't seem possible to check to see if an existing collection is capped.

The shell has `db.collection.isCapped()` but there is no equivalent that I can find in the .NET API. Another approach would be to get the stats for a collection and check for the `capped` flag, but I can't see how to do that either.

Comment: The shell should give you pointers here. Run `db.collection.stats` without the closing brackets `()` and you will see how this "JavaScript" function is implemented there. Basically you a are calling `db.runCommand({ "colStats": "collectionName" })` which returns an object of which has a property `capped` as a Boolean value for you to inspect. All drivers support a "dbcommand" method somewhere, as this is the basis of all operations sent to the MongoDB server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, There isn't `isCapped` in MongoDB.Driver 2.0. But you can get it from collection stats

```
public async Task<bool> IsCollectionCapped(string collectionName)
{
    var command = new BsonDocumentCommand<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument
    {
        {"collstats", collectionName}
    });

    var stats = await GetDatabase().RunCommandAsync(command);
    return stats["capped"].AsBoolean;
}
```