# How do you check if a collection is capped?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Before, using spring data mongo you could do something like `mongoClient.getDB(db_name).getCollection(collection_name).isCapped()`. But now the getDB is deprecated, you could still use it but there must be some other way to do it. 
I tried doing `mongoClient.getDatabase(db_name).getCollection(collection_name).some_function()` but there is no similar function like isCapped() now.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate.  A solution can be found here.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30706694/check-to-see-if-a-mongodb-collection-is-capped-with-the-net-2-0-driver

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve to find if a collection is capped by doing the following.

```
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoClient(), getDatabaseName());
Document obj = new Document();
obj.append("collStats", "yourCollection");
Document result = mongoTemplate.executeCommand(obj);
result.getBoolean("capped")
```